Keycloak production Failed to obtain JDBC connection
I have the same issue, but my configuration is without a dockerfile actually.
it's all in the docker-compose as follows:
qg_cms-db:
    container_name: qg_cms-db
    image: postgres:16-alpine
    networks:
      - qg_cms-network
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - PGPORT=5432
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - ./containers/data/postgres:/data/db
      - ./init-scripts:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U postgres" ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
  
  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:25.0.4
    command:
      - start
      - --optimized
    environment:
      - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin
      - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=verysecretpwd
      - KC_HOSTNAME_URL=https://myhost/
      - KC_HOSTNAME_ADMIN_URL=https://myhost/
      - KEYCLOAK_IMPORT=/opt/keycloak/data/import/realm.json
      - KC_PROXY=edge
      - PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true
      - LOG_LEVEL=ALL
      - KC_DB=postgres
      - KC_DB_URL=jdbc:postgresql://qg_cms-db/keycloak
      - KC_DB_URL=jdbc:postgresql://qg_cms-db/keycloak
      - KC_DB_USERNAME=postgres
      - KC_DB_PASSWORD=postgres
      - KC_LOG_LEVEL=DEBUG
      - KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT=false
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 8443:8443
    depends_on:
      - qg_cms-db
    networks:
      - qg_cms-network

I've tried many configurations and played around with it for a while but still receiving the same error:
ERROR: Failed to obtain JDBC connection
ERROR: Driver does not support the provided URL: jdbc:postgresql://qg_cms-db/keycloak


I have got the same error operating Keycloak as an Azure Container App with CosmosDB for PostgreSQL. Did you solve your problem?

Try checking a database name exists under the name keycloak. The database endpoint you used jdbc:postgresql://qg_cms-db/keycloak says keycloak. I'm assuming you already created database called keycloak or your initial script does it (docker-entrypoint-initdb.d). But if it doesn't, the endpoint is pointing to a database that does not exist.
